# Probability of having a match in an existing database

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine you are an airport authority in CountryLand and you have two passenger types: human passengers and animals. 
There is no way for you to distinguish between human passengers and animals except through a list that you have compiled over the years which maps a passenger name to an ID (made of 20 digits) and passenger type: human or animal.

You are mostly interested in identifying persons and you have a labeled list of 60,000 person names, their IDs, their type and their occurrence frequency. The total human population in CountryLand is 100 million and the animal population is 3.5 million in CountryLand.

- If you have in your database 2 million names that you would like to check as either humans or animals, what is the probability that the name already exists in the annotated list?
- What is the minimum number of persons' names you need to have in your annotated list to have an 80% probability of a match?